# How to show that if a relativized PH collapses, then PH collapses itself

Tags: complexity-theory

Let $A$ be an arbitrary set in PH. Suppose PH$^A$ collapses.

I am now asked to show that PH itself must collapse.

I have remarked that, since $A$ is in PH, $A$ must in particular be in one of the $\Sigma_i$'s, say $A\in\Sigma_n$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. Also, PH$^A$ collapses, so PH$^A = (\Sigma_m)^A$ for some $m\in\Bbb N$.

But from there, I am not able to finish the proof. Is this the right way to go, and how should I finish this proof?

**EDIT** The exact question is the following

1. Give a definition of PH
2. Fix any set $A$. What is the lowest lever of the relativized hierarchy 
   PH$^A$?
3. Suppose that $A\in\text{PH}$ and that PH$^A$ collapses. Show that PH collapses.

Of course, 1 and 2 are irrelevant.

Comment: Do you instead mean ​ "Suppose that for all sets A, PH$^{\hspace{.03 in}A}$ collapses." ? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: No, I am asked to show it for just one fixed $A$

Comment: In that case, does "arbitrary" mean that your result must work regardless of what A is or that you get to choose A? ​ ​

Comment: The former is the case, it must work regardless of what A is.

Comment: In that case, [the possibility of showing that] is equivalent to an open problem. ​ ​

Comment: Is it really? For completeness, I will edit my question to include the exact question asked, maybe I'm interpreting something wrong.

Comment: I would usually interpret that as you did, but maybe "Fix any set A." is supposed to let you choose A. $\hspace{.25 in}$ (PH[$^{QBF}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_quantified_Boolean_formula) is known to collapse.) ​ ​ ​ ​